# How to compute pairwise cosine similarity matrix between words in one text file

Tags: python, text, cosine-similarity

Hi All :) I'm trying to coding in python to compute (and print) a cosine similarity matrix between words in a text file.

So, for example what I have is this text file:

f.txt:
"hello my name is Sara and now I'm looking for your help"

the output should be like:

```
 hello  my  name  is  Sara  and  now  I'm  looking  for  your  help
```

hello   1        0.54      0.42 ... ........  ..........        ...

my

name

is

sara

and

now

I'm

looking

for

your

help

And so on. Any help to code that ?

this is my try:

```
import nltk
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
from sklearn.metrics.pairwise import cosine_similarity
tokens = []
with open('try.txt', 'r') as f:
for line in f.readlines():
    tokens += (nltk.word_tokenize(line)) # BC I have long file so this give me memory error
# Vectorise the data
vec = TfidfVectorizer()
X = vec.fit_transform(tokens)
S = cosine_similarity(X)

print(S)
```

Comment: Format code as code please.

Comment: Show your effort please? Remember that using others' code won't improve your programming skill.

Comment: These are two very different questions: 1) opening and reading from a file, 2) calculating cosine similarity on the contents of that file.

Comment: @blacksite So definitely too broad. Done.

Comment: I edit and added @user202729

Comment: look please for my code, I know these two Q's but cannot go with me @blacksite

Comment: @SaraWasl What do you mean? If there are 2 different questions you should ask 2 different questions.

Comment: (side note: [no "hi"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts))

Comment: I mean I know but my question is clear, is about "calculating cosine similarity on the contents of that file" @user202729

Comment: Imagine someone don't know how to read a text file, and visit Stack Overflow. Would they care that you are calculating cosine similarity?

Comment: Remember "too broad" is a close reason.

Comment: of course not, but I'm asking about specific thing, any help ? @user202729

Answer (score 0):

I think you misunderstand what the cosine similarity is. I suggest reading up on what comparing texts based on their cosine similarity involves exactly, but just to give you a rough idea: Cosine similarity is commonly used to compare two strings, where each string consists of multiple tokens. You first tokenize each string and then translate the tokens into vectors. While anything in a string can be a token, it is quite common to choose individual words as tokens.

In your example, each string just consists of one token, which is the word. So you are essentially asking: "What is the similarity between the string 'Hello' and the string 'Sara', using the words in each string as the unit of comparison". That doesn't make any sense. 'Hello' is not in 'Sara' and 'Sara' is not in 'Hello', so the similarity is 0. To show this, here is a working code for your example:

```
import nltk
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
from sklearn.metrics.pairwise import cosine_similarity

the_corpus = ['Hello',  'my',  'name', 'is', 'Sara', 'and', 'now', 'I\'m', 
'looking', 'for', 'your', 'help']
# Vectorise the data
vec = TfidfVectorizer()
X = vec.fit_transform(the_corpus)
S = cosine_similarity(X)
print(S)
```

The output is not really helpful.

```
[[1. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 1. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 1. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 1. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 1. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 1. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 1. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 1. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 1. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 1. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 1.]]
```

If you are interested in the similarity between individual words, there are a couple of things you can do. For instance, you could tokenize your strings using as tokens individual letters in the word. But what is more common is to use alternative concepts such as the "Minimum Edit Distance". It might make sense to read up on those as well.